# Should translations be done in the front end or back end?

Tags: mysql, json, reactjs, npm

So, We are writing manual translations for the site in French and English. It's built in `React` and the backend is `express` + `MySQL`. Now, there are a few ways to deal with translations and I was wondering what is the better way according to you guys

1. Front-End `json` file. (easy to use, easy to edit, would probably require shutting the server down if needs updating)
2. Back-End - `MySQL` tables. (returns promises, a little harder to deal with, however, wouldn't require us to restart the server to change a typo)
3. NPM - such as `react-localize-redux`

If there are any that I missed, let me know! and If you think one is better than the other one, I would really appreciate your input. Thank you, as always :)

Comment: "Wouldn't require us to restart the server to change a typo" or to add more languages/translations. That's enough reason for me to go with putting your non-code data in the database where it belongs.

Comment: @JNevill Wouldn't that add the overhead of network latency?

Comment: That seems like a small sacrifice given that every modern web application is sitting on top of a database. Surely we are talking about microseconds here because your database is going to be sitting physically close to your web server.

Comment: @JNevill I was talking about the network latency between the webserver and the client. I'm still in favor of that solution since data can be changed/added on-the-fly, swapping languages would always have to wait for a request to be resolved but it beats the other approaches, and I'd always delegate the task of having to go through larger datasets to collect data to a proper backend service in whichever stack instead of client-side Javascript.